# How to pass or retrieve values or requests from the lambda function to the external Database in amazon aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I currently know how to send values to the amazon database but I want to know how to send or get the values from the external Database to the lambda function using external API??

Comment: Which external Database??

Comment: MYSQL database.

Comment: This question needs **much** more detail.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to make a text bot using amazon lex and Aws lambda that shows the list of available restaurants and what it must do is that it must retrieve the details of the restaurants stored in the MYSQL database and then display the details to the user and then the user can book a reservation. I am a newbie and i don't know how to link the bot to the external MYSQL database..... So Please help me....